# DISTINCT ON equivalent solution for MYSQL? - Repex included

Tags: mysql, sql

My background is in R and I use SQL for simple bulky queries which I later refine with R, hence apologies for my pedantics.

I was forced to use PostgreSQL, but I know that what I am creating will be using MS MySQL for the deployment.

In PostgreSQL there is a way to select distinct columns and still pull the other columns that don't need to meet the distinct requirements.

For example, below Postgres version:

```
CREATE TABLE distinct_repex(
id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
invoice_num INT,
invoice_suffix INT,
company_name VARCHAR);
```

Populate example table:

```
INSERT INTO distinct_repex(invoice_num, invoice_suffix, company_name)
VALUES
('1234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('1234', '2', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('1234', '3', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('2234', '1', 'Saul Badman LLC'),
('2234', '2', 'Saul Badman LLC'),
('3234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('4234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('4234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('4234', '2', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('4234', '3', 'Saul Goodman LLC'),
('5234', '1', 'Ax-Capital LLC'),
('5234', '1', 'Ax-Capital LLC'),
('5234', '2', 'Ax-Capital LLC'),
('5234', '3', 'Ax-Capital LLC');
```

My desired query is to pull all records with distinct **invoice_num** and **invoice_suffix**, but I still need the other columns given the distinct condition.

Group BY in MySQL requires (to my limited knowledge) all columns from the SELECT to be present for the GROUP BY which in turn just brings everything because if comparing all columns, it just brings everything.

Another work around I imagine would be to identify all distinct **invoice_num** and **invoice_suffix** save it to a temporary table and then Left Join with the pair invoice and suffix to call the remaining columns such as **company_name**

I'm optimizing my SQL queries for a ShinyApp which generates a Dashboard. I'm forcing myself to pull as clean data as possible, but I still require the information in the other columns for analysis in R, hence the issue.

Any input is very welcome and I appreciate the time in advance.

Comment: You should also include what the expected output is, but a distinct select would seem to give you what you want here.

Comment: "MS MYSQL"?  There is "MS SQL" (also called "SQL Server", tag sql-server), and there is "MySQL"; there is no  "MS MYSQL"

Comment: Oh, it's not Mr. and Mrs. Sql?

Comment: Perhaps you need `GROUP_CONCAT(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter the pairs of `invoice_num` and `invoice_suffix` to instances where they only appear on one row in the table (perhaps that's what you mean by "distinct," although that explanation is throwing others off (or it's throwing me off)), then you can write the query you might be describing as an inline view, and then join into it to get the other column(s), like this:

```
select    x.*
from      distinct_repex            x
     join (
            select    invoice_num,
                      invoice_suffix
            from      distinct_repex
            group by  invoice_num,
                      invoice_suffix
            having    count(*) = 1
          )                         y
       on x.invoice_num     = y.invoice_num
      and x.invoice_suffix  = y.invoice_suffix;
```

If what I've described is not what you want, you might be wanting to show the other columns associated with a particular record within a given `invoice_num` and `invoice_suffix` pair, based on the order of other column(s) of the table. That is what `distinct on` does in Postgres. But what's confusing is that you didn't specify which column(s) you want ordered, and your example data has only one single third column, where the values don't even differ between the rows. So it's very confusing as to what you want. If in theory the example data included varying company names, and you wanted the first company in alphabetical order, that would look like the below. If your real table has a 4th, 5th, 6th... column, and you want the "chosen record" dictated by the order of certain other columns, you would have to tweak the below accordingly or provide a better example and explanation of what you want.

```
select    y.invoice_num,
          y.invoice_suffix,
          y.company_name
from      (
            select    x.*,
                      row_number() over(  partition by  invoice_num,
                                                        invoice_suffix
                                          order by      company_name
                                        ) as rn
            from      distinct_repex    x
          ) y
where     y.rn = 1;
```

The above should work in with MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server, if using the latest versions. It would be helpful if you say what database you are actually using.

Comment: thank you for your answer,

Your understood what I meant when using the distinct. I am trying to pull all pairs of "unique" **controlno** + **suffix** , no ordering required but I also need to be able to pull the other columns which contain pertinent information. I've never seen that use of syntax for SQL queries, where can I find a little more about the use of "x.*" - intermediate variables if I can even call it that. Haven't tried it yet, but I have better example with additional columns to exemplify what I meant. Stackoverflow doesn't allow enough characters to add new repex for reply.

Comment: The first query is what you're after, then. The `x` is just an alias I gave to the `inline view` which is a `subquery` in the `from` clause. Not all people call such a subquery an `inline view`, those who use Oracle opt for that term to distinguish such from subqueries elsewhere. You can read up on inline views (or "subqueries in the from clause") here: https://learnsql.com/blog/inline-query-in-sql/ You're querying the result of another query. Similar to tables or views, it's helpful (and usually required, depending on the database) to assign each table, view, or inline view, an alias

Comment: For clarification, the `x` could have been `a`, `b`, `c`, `fish`, or `dog` and it would run identically (as long as you change the prefix before each appropriate column name)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need a distinct query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT invoice_num, invoice_suffix, company_name
FROM distinct_repex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, if you don't care which value of the non-group by fields is used, you use MIN() or MAX(), e.g.:

```
select invoice_num, invoice_suffix, min(company_name)
from distinct_repex
group by invoice_num, invoice_suffix
```